# Configure custom Infinispan loader with JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan

we are migrating one application from JBoss AS 6 to 7.

This new instance is useing the standalone-ha profile. On the previous version, we used a custom Infinispan loader which stored the cache entries into our custom database.

Now, on JBoss 7.1, when trying to change this configuration using the visual administration console, it don't work. The value that we type on the tab "Store Class Impl" on "Replicated caches" is not being stored on the profile configuration as it should be. So, here is my question: is it possible to change this configuration using xml? How can I configure this custom loader for our replicated caches? Does anyone here ever experience this kind of dificulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't provide you any valuable information about JBoss admin console.

Anyway, I would suggest you to set up cache stores/loaders for your Infinispan caches declaratively (using configuration xml file) or programmatically (using fluent API builder just in code).

Here you can find more details about stores/loaders and some example configurations: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Cache+Loaders+and+Stores

And also take into account that in the recent Infinispan version (5.2) there is no possibility to change cache configuration "on fly". You need to restart your service with new configuration in case of any wanted change.

(What do you exactly mean by custom Infinispan loader?)